# Absolute path of a file inside a project package

Tags: java, file, jar, path, absolute

I've created a file inside a project package using this code:

```
File xmlFile = new File("src/com/company/project/xml/tags.xml");
```

I am able to read the file while running from eclipse. However, after creating .jar, I'm unable to read the file. So I want to put absolute path while reading the file from the project package. How it can be done? Help and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, IDE's will include no Java files in the resulting Jar.  Most IDE's will also include the `src` directory in the classpath when you run/debug the program from within them.

As a general rule of thumb, never include `src` in any path, `src` will simply not exist once the program is built.

Instead you need to make use of `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`, depending on your needs.  You should remember, you should never treat an "embedded" resource as a `File`, as in most cases it won't be, it'll be a stream of bytes in a zip file.

Something like...

```
URL xmlFile = getClass().getResource("/com/company/project/xml/tags.xml");
```

will return a `URL` reference to the resource.  Remember, if you need a `InputStream`, you'll have to `Class#getResourceAsStream`.

If you want the resource to be writable, then you will need to find a different location to store it, as embedded resources are read only

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getClass().getResource()`

`new File(getClass().getResource("src/com/company/project/xml/tags.xml").toURI());`

Comment: Assuming it's an embedded resource, in most cases you won't be able to access it as a `File`, because it won't be. Instead, you should juste use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` and use the returned `URL`/`InputStream` to read it. You should also never include `src` in any path value

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.